# How to import NetCDF file to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, netcdf, geotiff-tiff

I looked at the other similar questions posed and none of them seem to be answered.

Basically I have a NetCDF file with multiple subdatasets and from what I've read, I should be converting it to a TIFF file, which I can then import into PostgreSQL using raster2psql.  I'm trying to use gdal_translate command but I don't understand how to batch translate all of the subdatasets in one go.

Comment: Some raster2pgsql handle netCDF natively, so you may not need to use gdal_translate.  Do you see netCDF listed when you do:  raster2pgsql -G ?

Comment: maybe the [link](https://robertwb.wordpress.com/2016/02/20/netcdf-data-and-postgis/) helps, it shows how to import dataset from netcdf file to postgis. you could check it.